# TS2786 in every component and file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

Every single component that you can see in the code below is accused of TS2786, telling me "{component} cannot be used as a JSX component". This is a project that I have for a year now and I'm just doing maintenance. The code works perfectly, but I can't deploy it with the errors. I ran it in localhost and it is as intended.

This started happening just now, it was just ok the last time I updated it. According to the FramerMotion forum, their advice is to just insert @ts-ignore, but the issue is in every component, not just with theirs, and @ts-ignore doesn't work in this file. Also, the deployment error still occurs with the ts-ignore.

My versions:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.12",
  "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
  "@sanity/vision": "^3.35.1",
  "framer-motion": "^7.5.3",
  "next": "^14.0.2",
  "next-sanity": "^7.1.4",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  "react-hook-form": "^7.37.0",
  "react-hydration-provider": "^2.1.0",
  "react-simple-typewriter": "^4.0.5",
  "react-social-icons": "^5.15.0",
  "sanity": "^3.35.1",
  "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
  "swiper": "^8.4.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "18.8.3",
  "@types/react": "18.0.21",
  "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
  "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
  "eslint": "8.25.0",
  "eslint-config-next": "12.3.1",
  "postcss": "^8.4.17",
  "tailwind-scrollbar": "^2.1.0-preview.0",
  "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
  "typescript": "5.4.3"
}
```

UPDATE: running npx typesync or npm upgrade or adding resolutions didn't work at all!

Does anyone have any solution for this? Thank you so much!

```
import type { GetStaticProps } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";
import About from "../components/About";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Hero from "../components/Hero";
import Skills from "../components/Skills";
import Projects from "../components/Projects";
import Contact from "../components/Contact";
import Courses from "../components/Courses";
import Experiences from "../components/Experiences";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { HydrationProvider, Client } from "react-hydration-provider";
import { fetchPageInfo } from "../utils/fetchPageInfo";
import { fetchSkills } from "../utils/fetchSkills";
import { fetchProjects } from "../utils/fetchProjects";
import { fetchSocials } from "../utils/fetchSocials";
import { fetchExperiences } from "../utils/fetchExperience";
import { Course, Experience, PageInfo, Project, Skill, Social } from "../typings";
import { fetchCourses } from "../utils/fetchCourses";
import Link from "next/link";
import { HomeIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
import { Suspense } from "react";

type Props = {
  pageInfo: PageInfo;
  experiences: Experience[];
  courses: Course[];
  skills: Skill[];
  projects: Project[];
  socials: Social[];
};

const Home = ({ pageInfo, experiences, courses, skills, projects, socials }: Props) => {
  return (
    <HydrationProvider>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}> </Suspense>
      <Client>
        <div
          className="bg-[rgb(36,36,36)] text-white h-screen snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-y-scroll overflow-x-hidden z-0 
      scrollbar-thin scrollbar-track-gray-400/20 scrollbar-thumb-amber-400/40"
        >
          <Head>
            <title>Portfolio</title>
            <link rel="icon" href="/react.ico" />
          </Head>

          <Header socials={socials} />

          <section id="hero" className="snap-start">
            <Hero pageInfo={pageInfo} />
          </section>

          <section id="about" className="snap-center">
            <About pageInfo={pageInfo} />
          </section>

          <section id="experience" className="snap-center">
            <Experiences experiences={experiences} />
          </section>

          <section id="courses" className="snap-center">
            <Courses courses={courses} />
          </section>

          <section id="skills" className="snap-start">
            <Skills skills={skills} />
          </section>

          <section id="projects" className="snap-start">
            <Projects
              projects={projects}
            />
          </section>

          <section id="contact" className="snap-start">
            <Contact name={""} email={""} subject={""} message={""} />
          </section>
          
          <Link href={'#hero'}>
          <footer className="sticky bottom-5 w-full cursor-pointer">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
              <motion.div
                initial={{
                  opacity: 0,
                }}
                animate={{
                  opacity: 1,
                }}
                transition={{
                  duration: 1.2,
                  delay: 0.5,
                }}
                className="h-8 w-8 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center"
              >
                <HomeIcon className="h-7 w-17 pb-0.5 hover:grayscale-100 text-[#F7AB0A] animate-pulse" />
              </motion.div>
            </div>
          </footer>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </Client>
    </HydrationProvider>
  );
};

export default Home;

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<Props> = async () => {
  const pageInfo: PageInfo = await fetchPageInfo();
  const experiences: Experience[] = await fetchExperiences();
  const courses: Course[] = await fetchCourses();
  const skills: Skill[] = await fetchSkills();
  const projects: Project[] = await fetchProjects();
  const socials: Social[] = await fetchSocials();

  return {
    props: {
      pageInfo,
      experiences,
      courses,
      skills,
      projects,
      socials,
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
};
```

**SOLUTION:** as I found out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71841181/some-components-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component), just run npm i react@18 react-dom@18 @types/react@18 @types/react-dom@18. Thanks!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71831601/ts2786-component-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component) looks very similar to the one you're asking here.

Comment: I stumbled upon that post as well, but it seems that the solution is to degrade React to version 17, which I'm not too keen on doing...

Comment: It talks about degrading the react types to 17, not react (although it's not a great solution to have the mismatch between the package and the types)

Comment: yeah, and mine's are not that distant either way... I tried adding resolutions for both to 18.2.0, deleted node_modules, tried npm upgrade @types/react and its version stayed the same, still no fix